# ValueError - How to Extend OAuth2 Application Model - Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want extend Application model of django oauth toolkit. They have given intsructions here [link](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-model)

But i am not getting how to do it. I have created one app inside apps folder and inside models i have added the following code.

```
from django.db import models
from oauth2_provider.models import AbstractApplication

class MyApplication(AbstractApplication):
    logo = models.ImageField()
    agree = models.BooleanField()
```

Resgitered the app inside `installed_apps` as `'apps.oauth2',` and added the following line:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL='apps.OAuth2'
```

But it giving me error

> LookupError: No installed app with label 'apps'.

```
Installed Apps [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',

    'apps.commons',
    'apps.company',
    'apps.oauth2',
]
```

Comment: Have you put apps in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: yes `'apps.oauth2'` oauth2 is my app inside apps folder

Comment: Can you show your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Here i added Please see it. When i remove `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL='apps.OAuth2' ` The error goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this manual [link](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-) model in `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL` should be **class name**  not app

Comment: ValueError: Invalid model reference 'apps.oauth2.models.MyApplication'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.

Comment: `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL=app_name.ModelClass`. No need to write `app_name.model.ModelClass`

Comment: YAY It worked - `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL='oauth2.MyApplication'` Tank you